# Could You clarify me with for each

Tags: php, foreach

I cannot understand a foreach operator.
Possible I leave that world in ignorance. Of course I had read tutorials for newbies and read samples, but if a little bit more than one argument then it is a black box for me... So today I have data source as follows:

```
Array ( [error] => [warning] => [status] => 0 [fields] => Array ( [0] => content ) [attrs] => Array ( [path] => 7 ) [matches] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [weight] => 1319 [attrs] => Array ( [path] => /home/test1.txt ) ) [2] => Array ( [weight] => 1319 [attrs] => Array ( [path] => /home/test2.txt ) ) [3] => Array ( [weight] => 1319 [attrs] => Array ( [path] => /home/test3.txt ) ) ) [total] => 3 [total_found] => 3 [time] => 0.000 [words] => Array ( [test1] => Array ( [docs] => 3 [hits] => 3 ) ) )
```

I found suitable sample for it!

```
foreach ( $result["matches"] as $ID => $info ) {
      echo $ID." "; print_r($info); echo "<br>";
}

1 Array ( [weight] => 1319 [attrs] => Array ( [path] => /home/test1.txt ) ) 
2 Array ( [weight] => 1319 [attrs] => Array ( [path] => /home/test2.txt ) ) 
3 Array ( [weight] => 1319 [attrs] => Array ( [path] => /home/test3.txt ) ) 
                    }
```

I cannot understand how it works!

1. Why when I change ID on IDD or info on inf the program still works? How those variables connect to data?
2. How I should change my foreach for getting:

`/home/test1.txt
/home/test2.txt
/home/test3.txt`

Comment: the left part of "as" is the 'input' of the foreach: typically an array, or an iterable object/class. The right part is the 'output' in form `$key => $value`. So how you name the 2 variables on the right side is totally up to you, as long as you use the same name inside the loop later.

Comment: `as $ID` is similar to `$ID=` so you can use any variable name you want because the value will be assigned to the new variable `$ID`.

Comment: @Jeff nailed the first question. For the second you can use `echo($info['attrs']['path]);` instead of `print_r($info);`.

Comment: Thanks all! Now I see as ANY variables get value! It is clear now. Code is works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left part of "as" is the 'input' of the foreach: typically an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), or an [iterable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) object/class.

The right part (`$ID => $info`) is the 'output' in form `$key => $value`. How you name the 2 variables on the right side is totally up to you, as long as you use the same name inside the loop later.

In a normal sentence the syntax of foreach would be something like:

```
//For each (item of that) group   give me it's key and a    copy of the item     

foreach(                 $array   as           $key =>      $value) {

}
```

[The Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) describe it that way:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).
>
> The second form will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key variable on each iteration.